# Make a path from multiple connectors (in draw.io or other free tool)

Tags: path, line, connector, draw.io

is it possible in draw.io to associate multiple connectors/lines to a path, so that when I select one of these connectors/lines (or hover a mouser over it or something else) then I also see (e.g. highlighted) the whole path?

### Example

Sample diagram:

```
(Shape C1)
|
| connector Z1
|
(Shape A1) <--- connector X1 ---> (Shape A2) <--- connector X2 ---> (Shape A3) <--- connector X3 ---> (Shape A4)
|
| connector Z2
|
(Shape B1) <--- connector Y1 ---> (Shape B2) <--- connector Y2 ---> (Shape B3) <--- connector Y3 ---> (Shape B4)
```

For the above diagram I would like to create one path from connectors X1, X2, X3, and another path from Y1, Y2, Y3, and another from Z1, Z2.

This way shape A1 would actually have multiple paths coming through it - X path and Z path. Similarly shape B1 would be terminating two paths - Z path and Y path.

The **main purpose** is that I can always see the path, distinct from many other paths in a dense and multishape connection diagrom.

Addidionally perhaps there could be extra functionality: on these paths I could do some common operations - like for example change line color etc for all connectors in the path. This clould be for example by making a "multiple select" (like holding Ctrl and clicking) for all connectors in the path. But this is less important.

### So the question is

**is ANY of this functionality implemented in draw.io or in any other free diagramming tool?**

Comment: Drawio docs recommend using the special "Waypoint Shape" to join connectors. See: [Joining Connectors](https://drawio-app.com/blog/connection-points-functionality-and-customization-in-project-management)